# OneSignal postNotification Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to post a notification to all registered users with OneSignal.

I have a couple of users registered to test with and have successfully sent a notification form the OneSignal website dashboard.

However, when I try the following code, I get the following errors:

```
[OneSignal postNotification:@{
                             @"contents" : @{ @"en" : @"Test Message" },
                             @"object" : @{ @"en" : @"Test Title" },
                             @"app_id" : @"MY_SECRET_APP_ID",
                             } 
                 onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *result) {

                 } 
                 onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                 }];
```

**Error:**

`Create notification failed` and `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OneSignalError error 400.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a targeting parameter, only `include_player_ids` may be used from your app. All other targeting parameters such as tags or segments must be used from your server through the OneSignal [create notification](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API POST call. You can get the current OneSignal user / player id by calling [IdsAvailable](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-api#IdsAvailable).

To send a notification to all users from your server you will need to add the following to your JSON

```
"included_segments": ["All"],
```

Also note, `object` isn't a valid key so it will be ignored. I believe you are looking for `headings` based on the value you have.